# SQL query from highest value from duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this.

```
username | vendor | time
-------------------------
x        |  a     | 10
x        |  b     | 11
x        |  c     | 12
y        |  a     | 9
y        |  c     | 14
```

I want to pull out the rows with the highest time value among their usernames, so it should look like this:

```
username | vendor | time
-------------------------
x        |  c     | 12
y        |  c     | 14
```

I have no idea how to go about this after a couple queries didn't get what I wanted. What would this look like? Thanks!

Comment: tag the question with *one* database you are using. i removed multiple tags.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is fairly database agnostic:

```
SELECT username, vendor, MAX(time)
FROM foo
WHERE vendor = 'c'
GROUP BY username, vendor;
```

If it were me, I would want to use an analytic function (personal preference, really). This is supported in both MS SQL Server and Oracle:

```
SELECT username, vendor, MAX(time) OVER (PARTITION BY username, vendor)
FROM foo
WHERE vendor = 'c';
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40c4f/5).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANSI standard window function `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username order by time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Since the user didn't specify, I would assume that they're using MySQL which does not support the window clause.

Comment: @Jacobm001 . . . That is an incredibly useless and presumptuous assumption.

Comment: Not really. It's easily the most common database amongst beginners, which the OP clearly is. It's just worth noting that your solution is platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the OP wants a vendor filter, so the following will get the top `time` for each `username`, and the linked `vendor`.

This is making the same assumption as Jacobm001 that it is MySQL

```
select * from (select username, vendor, time from foo order by time desc) as t
group by username
```

Where `foo` is the name of your table

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e71f/2)